# people suggestion list not shown during we entered first letter itself in android

Tags: android

In search option, the user suggestion list not shown during we entered first letter itself.The suggestion will display after the second letter entered in the search bar.Anyone give the possible solution for this question.`

```
 search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(s, new Filter.FilterListener() {
                    public void onFilterComplete(int count) {
                        Log.d("log", "result count:" + count);
                        if (count == 0) {
                            usermsg.setText("No username found");
                            usermsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            peoplelist.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        } else {
                            usermsg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            peoplelist.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(final Editable s) {

                adapter.getFilter().filter(s, new Filter.FilterListener() {
                    public void onFilterComplete(int count) {
                        Log.d("log", "result count:" + count);
                        if (text.equals("people")) {
                            //movieList.clear();
                            getPeople();
                            if (count == 0) {
                                usermsg.setText("No username found");
                                usermsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                peoplelist.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            } else {
                                usermsg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                peoplelist.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                        } else if (text.equals("tag")) {
                            getTag(s);
                                usermsg.setText("# No Hash Tag found");
                                usermsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                peoplelist.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                             /*else {
                                usermsg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                peoplelist.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }*/
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });`
```

Comment: You can perform opertion in yours onTextChanged or afterTextChanged...Why are you performing operation in the both method of the addTextChangedListener method of the edittext....

Comment: what can i do to display the people list while typing first letter in edittext box

Comment: You have to maintain to arraylist...one is for all the data and another is for the shortest data from filter.....

Comment: I can't get clear idea

Comment: If i type the second letter means the list will shown

Comment: ..plz chcek the below solution and let me know in case of concern

Answer (score 0):

You have to maintain two `ARRAYLIST`, one for yours all data in `ListView` and another for the filter data...

So in my below solution i have two `ArrayList` one is for all data that is name **FULL_DATA_ARRAYLIST** and another for the **FILTER_ARRAYLIST** , So plz refers below solution that is:-

```
      search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (s.toString().length() == 0) {

                     usermsg.setText("No username found");
                     usermsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



                    adapter = new YOURADAPTERCLASS(YOUR_ACTIVITY.this, FULL_DATA_ARRAYLIST);
                    peoplelist.setAdapter(adapter);
                } else {

                        usermsg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        peoplelist.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                    FILTER_ARRAYLIST.clear();
                    for (int i = 0; i < FULL_DATA_ARRAYLIST.size(); i++) {
                        if (FULL_DATA_ARRAYLIST.get(i).getName().toLowerCase().contains(s.toString().toLowerCase()))
                            FILTER_ARRAYLIST.add(FULL_DATA_ARRAYLIST.get(i));
                    }
                    adapter = new YOURADAPTERCLASS(YOUR_ACTIVITY.this, FILTER_ARRAYLIST);
                    peoplelist.setAdapter(adapter);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: How to create a filter array list

Comment: ArrayList <String> FILTER_ARRAYLIST = new ArrayList<String>;

Comment: @suriya .. Is it helpful for you , than plz accept it as a useful answer :)

Comment: I think ,you are doing some minor mistake while using above code..The same code i have used in my app, and it is working fine..anyway all the best and ..and keep happy coading